# Dimension of $\mathbb R ^A$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How do we determine the dimension of $\mathbb R ^A$ for a set $A$ of either infinite or finite cardinality?

My intuition is that when $A$ is infinite, the dimension of $\mathbb R ^A$ must also be infinite. Specifically its base must be uncountably infinite, as $\mathbb R ^\mathbb N$ is proved to have an uncountably infinite base, and $\mathbb N$ is the "smallest" infinite cardinality. Am I wrong?

For the finite case let's say $|A|=n$. It must be that $\dim(\mathbb R ^A)=n$. How would i prove that?

Comment: If $A$ has finite cardinality $n$, then $\Bbb{R}^A$ is obviously isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^{\{ 1, \dots, n\} } = \Bbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, assuming the axiom of choice (saying that $\Bbb N$ is the "smallest" set of infinite cardinality requires that every infinite set is either "bigger or smaller" than $\Bbb N$, i.e. comparable).

If $A = \{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$, then we may show that $\dim \Bbb R^A = n$ by noting that the map $\phi: \Bbb R^A \to \Bbb R^n$ given by
$$
\phi(f) = (f(a_1),\dots,f(a_n))
$$
is an isomorphism of vector spaces.

Comment: For more on that parenthetical remark, see the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set#Relation_to_the_axiom_of_choice) on Dedekind infinite sets.

Comment: Correct, i meant that the cardinality of $\mathbb N$ is the smallest infinite cardinality (the cardinality of countably infinite sets).

Comment: @ManoPlizzi even that depends on your choice of axioms